# Fixed position navigation theme for drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, themes, drupal-themes

Does anyone know about any drupal theme with fixed navigation like http://designshack.net/articles/inspiration/20-examples-of-fantastic-fixed-position-navigation/
If not, does anyone how difficult it would be to develop one for someone like me? I have experience in programming but never touched CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery to make a sticky navigation](http://www.benmarshall.me/jquery-sticky-navigation/), or try out this sandbox module [Sticky Navigation](https://drupal.org/sandbox/skein/2030747).